# apache, ugswi, flask, problem with communication

Tags: flask, routes, load-balancing, uwsgi

I have a problem with my little project.
I'm trying to implement loadbalancer on apache web serwer 
whose will be sending all incoming requests to two application servers 
with uwsgi + flask.

```
My web serwer ip is: 10.0.0.10
App1: 10.0.0.8
App2: 10.0.0.9
```

Everything is fine when i have situation like:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def index():
   return render_template('heh.html')
```

Then my url is 10.0.0.10 and the content of heh.html is displayed. So this is good but..

My problem starting when I'm trying to route to different location like:

```
@app.route('/project/')
def project():
   return "I'm App 1"
```

when I trying to connect using browser with:
10.0.0.10/projects
Then my url is changing to 10.0.0.8/projects or 10.0.0.9/projects
and I have information that "Connection rejected"

My Apache configuration on web server below:

```
<Proxy balancer://mycluster>
BalancerMember http://10.0.0.8:8081
BalancerMember http://10.0.0.9:8081
</Proxy>

<Location /balancer-manager>
SetHandler balancer-manager
</Location>

ProxyPass /balancer-manager !
ProxyPass / balancer://mycluster/
```

Uwsgi config on app nodes:

```
[uwsgi]
chdir = /opt/uwsgi
wsgi-file = myflaskapp.py
http-socket = :8081
processes = 20
threads = 10
stats = :8082
callable = app
uid = klopsiu
harakiri = 50
logto = /var/log/uwsgi/uwsgi.log
```

My application file:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for, current_app

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('heh.html')

@app.route('/projects/')
def projects():
    return "I'm app 1"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
```

Please advise.
I don't want to use any proxy reverse I want everything to come in and come out
by loadbalancer.

Thanks and waiting for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was my mistake I forgot that when I trying to access some flask url I just need to add / on the end like:
10.0.0.10/database/